# how can i set a shell console on the bottom such as python and R consloe in gedit?

Tags: shell, gedit

I have installed python and R plugin in gedit,you can see the attachment,when i want to input shell command,i have to select `tools-external tools-run command`,and input shell command,it is not convenient for me to do that way,how can i set a shell console in the bottom of gedit gui such as python console and R console?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

it seems that [this plugin for gedit](http://mylinuxbook.com/embedded-terminal-a-gedit-plugin/) does precisely what you want. Hope this helps.